# Кросплатформенная разработка игр

Tags: разработка-игр

Интересно знать как разработчики игр портируют свой код на на несколько платформ (windows, linux, ps, xbox и т.п)?

У меня пока тока три варианта:

1) пишут универсальный код для разных платформ

2) адаптируют уже написанный код под платформу

3) разработка с нуля

Comment: Порой, достаточно при разработке использовать кроссплатформенную технологию. Например, JAVA+встроенная в него графическая библиотека, как это было при разработке MineCraft.

Comment: ну в вашем комментарии я вижу слово java и понимаю что все это будет крутится в виртуальной машине вследствие этого теряем скорость вычислений. да MineCraft удачный проект но графика там низкого качества.

Comment: Скорость вычислений? Хм, будто бы вы будете создавать что-то хотя бы на уровне майнкрафта) Для кроссплатформенных змеек и крестиков-ноликов ощутимой "потери скорости вычислений" не будет.

Comment: игру я писать вообще не собираюсь мне просто любопытно как это в больших проектах делается и все. кроссплатфлорменные крестики и нолики у меня улыбку вызывают )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1), в особых случаях - 2).

Ко всему прочему могут использоваться специальные системы автоматического портирования.

К тому же портировать приходится только аппаратно-зависимые компоненты программ: логика игр, меню, модели и текстуры не требуют переписывания или перерисовки на каждую платформу.

Answer (score 1):

На ум приходит Qt + OpenGL = убер кроссплатформенность.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно популярный вариант для решения кроссплатформенности - создание браузерной игры

Comment: а в этой категории разве можно написать что то из "тяжелых" игр?

Comment: @perfect, кстати можно, тот-же nacl, только вот кроссплатформенностью и не пахнет

Comment: уже вполне можно. в т.ч. и с 3Д